# About vfork() system call?

Tags: c, posix, vfork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   pid_t child_pid = vfork();

   if(child_pid < 0)
   {
       printf("vfork() error\n");
       exit(-1);
   }
   if(child_pid != 0)
   {
       printf("Hey I am parent %d\nMy child is %d\n",getpid(),child_pid);
       wait(NULL);
   }

   else
   {
       printf("Hey I am child %d\nMy parent is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
       execl("/bin/echo","echo","hello",NULL);
       exit(0);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 Hey I am child 4
 My parent is 3
 Hey I am parent 3
 My child is 4
 hello
```

My question : Why is "hello" printed after the execution of parent process?
 I have started learning about vfork(). Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It's *undefined behavior*: "*the behavior is undefined if the process created by `vfork()` [...] calls any other function before successfully calling `_exit(2)` or one of the `exec(3)` family of functions.*" ([`vfork(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html))

Comment: In 2017 on modern hardware you'll better consider `vfork` as obsolete. Why can't you use `fork` ? You should **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it a lot

Answer (score 2):

After the parent process is executed, it goes to `wait(NULL);` which blocks the parent process until the child process calls `execl()` or `exit`.

Therefore the child process when the parent is blocked is calling the `execl()` and thus `hello` is being printed in the end of the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
pid_t child_pid = vfork();

if(child_pid < 0)
{
   printf("vfork() error\n");
   exit(-1);
}
if(child_pid != 0)
{
   printf("Hey I am parent %d\nMy child is %d\n",getpid(),child_pid);
   wait(NULL);
 }

 else
 {
   printf("Hey I am child %d\nMy parent is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
   execl("/bin/echo","echo","hello",NULL);
   exit(0);
  }
 return 0;
  }
```

If you remove `execl()` the child process will go to the `exit(0)` and `hello` wont be printed.

Also, after `execl()` is being executed it is creating a new process thus any code you write after `execl()` wont be executed.
According to the man page:-

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image. The functions described in this manual page are front-ends for execve(2). (See the manual page for execve(2) for further details about the replacement of the current process image.)

Comment: "*goes to wait(NULL); which blocks the parent process until the child process calls execl() or exit.*" <- `wait()` won't be unblocked by a call to `execl()` in the child.

Answer (score 2):

A piece of advice first: Don't use `vfork()`. On a modern system, the advantages of using `vfork()` over `fork()` are tiny. The code you show can never work properly with `vfork()` because it invokes *undefined behavior*:

**POSIX.1:**

> The `vfork()` function has the same effect as `fork()`,
>          except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by
>          `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t`
>          used to store the return value from `vfork()`, or returns from the
>          function in which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function
>          before successfully calling `_exit()` or one of the `exec()` family of
>          functions.

So by calling `printf()` in your child code, your code is already undefined. Note that even a call to `exit()` would lead to undefined behavior, only [`_exit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) is allowed.

---

I assume you try this on Linux, which defines the behavior of `vfork()` a bit more and in a way that explains what you observe:

**From the linux [`vfork()` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html):**

> `vfork()` differs from `fork(2)` in that the calling thread is suspended
>          until the child terminates (either normally, by calling `_exit(2)`, or
>          abnormally, after delivery of a fatal signal), or it makes a call to
>          `execve(2)`.  Until that point, the child shares all memory with its
>          parent, including the stack.

So on Linux, you can be sure that the child created by `vfork()` is executed first and only by your call to `execl()` (which calls `execve()` internally), the parent process is allowed to continue running. That's the reason you see the parent's output after your child's output. Once the parent calls `wait()`, it waits until the child finishes -- at this point, the child is replaced by `echo`.

Relying on this behavior makes your program non-portable to different implementations of `vfork()`. The call to `printf()` is fine because Linux suspends the parent process, and the **wrong** call to `exit()` doesn't matter here by luck: anything after an `exec*()` call is unreachable anyways (those functions never return, they **replace** the running program)!

Because of its weird semantics and the huge risk of bugs, `vfork()` was *removed* from POSIX in POSIX.1-2008. A safe and modern POSIX replacement for the typical usecase of a `vfork()` directly followed by a `exec*()` is [`posix_spawn()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn).

---

All in all, you really shouldn't use `vfork()`. Use `fork()` instead. Remove the unreachable call to `exit()` as well and your program looks fine.

Comment: There is is still a fair bit of overhead in `fork`, particularly the memory reservation, faulting out all writable pages in the parent process for copy-on-write. On modern systems I would advice using `posix_spawn` where appropriate. Though of course this is all entirely irrelevant for the particular code above.

Comment: @doynax still a relevant hint to the general topic, I included it in an appropriate place of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. As you mentioned the behavior of vfork() is undefined. I used fork(), it is working well now. Thank you. I really needed this.